# Angularjs display dynamic ID and info of particular User in $scope when login with Service and API to fetch in MySQL

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, angularjs, api

I had this problem for AngularJS UI. I created a service to fetch a get method api /member/item/ + id, where my parameter id is the specified userID in my database table. I already setup a controller but I keep getting an error. Somehow I manage to get the ID of the user when I declare the value as 1. But I tried to make it dynamic it gives me error.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $window, $rootScope, adminService){
$scope.usertype = localStorage.usertype;
$rootScope.usertype = localStorage.usertype;
$rootScope.userID = localStorage.userID;
$scope.username = localStorage.username;

// $scope.userID = 1;
$scope.id= $scope.userID;
// $scope.userID = localStorage.userID;
adminService.editMember($scope.id)
    .then(function(data){
    //array
    $scope.id = data.data[0].userID;
    $scope.f_name = data.data[0].first_name;
    $scope.email = data.data[0].email;
});
```

});

**Service**

```
function editMember(id) {
    return $http({
        method: 'get',
        url: rootURL + '/member/item/' + id,
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
    })
}
```

**MemberInfo.html**

```
 <div class="card-body">
  <h6 class="card-title mb-1 large">
  <a href="#" class="col-xs-10" >
    <h4>FirstName: {{f_name}}, </h4>
    <label >ID: {{uid}}</label>
  </a>
  <label class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="editInfo"><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" for="editInfo" name="editInfo" ng-model="editInfo"> <ic class="fa fa-pencil"></i></label>
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveProfile()">
    <label>{{uid}}</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
          <label>Role : </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role" ng-model="usertype" readonly>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <label>Email : </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="email" ng-readonly="!editInfo">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: *I keep getting an error*. What is the `error`?

Comment: { "message": "Slim Application Error", "exception": [ { "type": "PDOException", "code": "42S22", "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'", "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\A_a\\wemis\\api\\src\\routes.php", "line": 283, this is the error in my routes.php –

Comment: $app->get('/{tablecode}/item/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) { $tb_code = $args['tablecode']; $id = $args['id']; $dbLocal = $this->db_local; $query = ""; if($tb_code == "user") $query = "SELECT * FROM bk_user WHERE userID=$id"; elseif($tb_code == "member") $query = "SELECT * FROM bk_user_profile WHERE profileID=$id"; $stmt = $dbLocal->query($query) (the line where i get error) $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); echo json_encode($result); });

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are defining `uid` but `uid` is not even present in the controller, is this a typo?

For helping you debug the issue. I have mocked up the HTTP request, the code seems fine, except for this one typo.

**Before:**

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h6 class="card-title mb-1 large">
  <a href="#" class="col-xs-10" >
    <h4>FirstName: {{f_name}}, </h4>
    <label >ID: {{uid}}</label>
  </a>
  <label class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="editInfo"><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" for="editInfo" name="editInfo" ng-model="editInfo"> <ic class="fa fa-pencil"></i></label>
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveProfile()">
    <label>{{uid}}</label>
```

**After:**

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h6 class="card-title mb-1 large">
  <a href="#" class="col-xs-10" >
    <h4>FirstName: {{f_name}}, </h4>
    <label >ID: {{id}}</label>
  </a>
  <label class="btn btn-primary pull-right" name="editInfo"><input type="checkbox" class="hidden" for="editInfo" name="editInfo" ng-model="editInfo"> <ic class="fa fa-pencil"></i></label>
  <form name="myForm" ng-submit="saveProfile()">
    <label>{{id}}</label>
```

---

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @SkyeUnknown Was this answer helpful to you? or are you facing issues?

Comment: I did what you said, I changed the uid to id and it still gives me some error. There an error in my API, but when I use postman to test my api it has no error.

Comment: {
    "message": "Slim Application Error",
    "exception": [
        {
            "type": "PDOException",
            "code": "42S22",
            "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'undefined' in 'where clause'",
            "file": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\A_a\\wemis\\api\\src\\routes.php",
            "line": 283, **this is the error in my routes.php**

Comment: $app->get('/{tablecode}/item/{id}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $tb_code = $args['tablecode'];
  $id = $args['id'];
  $dbLocal = $this->db_local;
  $query = "";
  if($tb_code == "user") $query = "SELECT * FROM bk_user WHERE userID=$id"; elseif($tb_code == "member") $query = "SELECT * FROM bk_user_profile WHERE profileID=$id";
  **$stmt = $dbLocal->query($query) (the line where i get error)**
  $result =  $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); echo json_encode($result);  });